# Word not connecting to WebDAV server

Tags: ms-word, webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I'm currently implementing the Class 2 WebDAV server on my company's MVC / noSQL web app. I'm developing it locally on my machine using visual studio 2013, IIS 8.5, Windows 8.1 and word 365. The documents are stored in the noSQL database.

I've managed to get it working in the past, however recently word refuses to connect to the WebDAV server. When I click the document link it open word and the following error appears:

{ correct web address} cannot connect to server.

I have used your built in logging tool and fiddler to see if any requests are made to the server and there are none.

Are there any steps or suggestion you can make to help me debug this problem.

Comment: Could you clarify, are you sure you are using Office 365 or is it a desktop version of Microsoft Office? Could you please also post a screenshot of the error.

Comment: The version of office I'm using is Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013. I have sent the screenshots to your email address showing the error. Thank you @ITHitWebDAV

Comment: Are there any errors in the web browser console (press F12)? One of the reasons - IT Hit WebDAV Ajax Library probably did not load. You will see "ITHit is not defined" or similar error in web browser console in this case.

Comment: If you downloaded the IT Hit WebDAV Ajax Library trial version it has a limitation of 1 month. To start a new trial period just redownload it from http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/download/ (the archive is generated dayly with a new verification code inserted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the documentation a few times and trial and error I found that word was caching in the registry. I followed the instructions and rebuilt my project and it seems to have worked.

http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/ms_office_read_only

Clear Microsoft Office WebDAV cache in registry. Microsoft Office reads WebDAV server options when connecting to server first time and stores them for later use. If your server settings has changed during development (or you just fixed some server issues) you may need to delete this settings. The Microsoft Office WebDAV cache is stored under the key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\\Common\Internet\Server Cache\

To clear cache just delete all keys under this key. In a development environment we suggest always clearing the cache if your WebDAV server class has changed or after authentication scheme has changed. As an alternative to deleting cache, you can just reconfigure your server to run on a different port.

Note that in production environment usually you do not need to clear this cache or change port as soon as you server settings do not change often while Microsoft Office will re-request server options after some time.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your code worked in the past and now stopped working I guess that the trial period, which is 1 month, of IT Hit WebDAV Ajax Library has ended. Are there any errors in the web browser console? To start a new trial period just redownload it [here](http://webdavsystem.com/ajax/download).